# Dual boot shows ubuntu and windows, but windows is not loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have installed windows 10 first and then ubuntu 16.04. after that ubuntu was showing in the boot. I saw some tutorial in online found that I have to update my grub or something. I followed the step and now ubuntu and windows both are there in boot. but the problem is it's not loading while I select the windows. while I select the windows blank screen comes up with default boot color and hand there for forever. what can I do? please help.

Comment: Can you boot to Win10 from UEFI via F9 or F10 keys?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows or no hibernation. Did you turn off fast start up in Windows? You may need to directly boot Windows as posted above to change settings. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean default Ubuntu purple colour? First, you should check whether Windows will boot up independently of Ubuntu, ie on BIOS Boot Menu, not GRUB menu. It can be a little tricky if you haven't done this before.

To do that, start your computer and immediately select the appropriate function key and tap it quickly. I can't say which F number that is as it varies according to your computer model (on mine it's F12 key). Look it up in your manual or google for it. Sometimes it appears for a second at the bottom of the screen when you switch on. Assuming you already know or you find that key, and you have the BIOS boot menu up on screen, select Windows Boot Manager (or any similar sounding option name) and ENTER. If Windows fails to start up then you know it's a Windows boot problem, and  perhaps you should look [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html), [or try this](https://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/) and choose 'Repair your computer', or search or ask a question in this [forum](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/) to resolve it. If Windows boots up correctly, then it's a GRUB issue. Let us know and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may try boot-repair on Ubuntu http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/install-boot-repair-ppa-fix-boot-problems/